# How to get another object in the same json array with id using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

While filling the form i am sending the id of `closedBy` selected item like this

```
if (selectedClosedPlaces != undefined) {
            place.closedBy = selectedClosedPlaces.map(function(g) {
                return g._id;
            });
        } else {
            place.closedBy = ['no_name'];
        }
```

i am displaying it in html using {{place.closedBy}}. 
i will be having json data like this

```
[{"_id":"56bc720bd0113ab80dd3cb2d","name":{"en":"fshu","de":"hfasj"},"closedBy":["no_name"],"category":{"_id":"56bb2999f197db040dc3b12b","name":{"en":"asdfdsf","de":"asdf"}}}},
{"_id":"56bc7238d0113ab80dd3cb2e","name":{"en":"jsfadk","de":"jkgdj"},"closedBy":["56bc720bd0113ab80dd3cb2d"],"category":{"_id":"56bb2999f197db040dc3b12b","name":{"en":"asdfdsf","de":"asdf"}}}}]
```

For the first one it will be null, so i gave some name like `['no_name']`. after adding the first one only i can select closedBy using selectbox.

 now i am returning id for the second one. i am having id for the second one in closedBy using, please check the json above. with that id i need to fetch that particular name 
Example: i am having `56bc720bd0113ab80dd3cb2d` id with this id i need to show that name.en and name.de =>`fshu and hfasj` .
i am using service to get the values 
 **//service code here**

```
.service('PlaceService', function($http) {
    return {
        init: function(callback) {
            $http.get('/api/places').then(function(place_response) {
                callback(place_response);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**and in controller**

```
PlaceService.init(function(place_response) {
            $scope.places = place_response.data;
        console.log($scope.places); //giving all the places details like the //above json.
       console.log($scope.places.closedBy); // Not giving closedBy value here
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: Have read this 3 times and can't figure out what you are asking

Comment: i am getting **if (selectedClosedPlaces != undefined) {
            place.closedBy = selectedClosedPlaces.map(function(g) {
                return g._id;
            });
        } else {
            place.closedBy = ['no_name'];
        }**
i am getting _id with this javascript code, i need to show the name.en and name.de with that particular id which i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find another **first** item with specific id inside array of objects you can use [_underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) js lib, like this:

```
var yourWantedId = ...;    
var result = _.findWhere(selectedClosedPlaces, {"_id": yourWantedId });
```